# Return string on web page between two different words/strings in perl

Tags: perl, search, html

All,
  I realise against gooogle ToC but I was trying to write a perl script that performs a google search and returns the number of hits (eg the 1 of about XXXX for search term). I should state I am perl newbie.

After reading etc this is what I have but it does not return any thing and I'm not sure why...can anyone give me some pointers.

```
use LWP::Simple;

my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0');

my $url=$ARGV[0];
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
my $res = $ua->request($req);

$res->content;  

print "all done \n";    

while ($res ==~ /of about <b>([1234567890,]<\/b> +)/) {
  print $res;
}
```

Comment: You need to run the regex against `$res->content`, not the response object.

Comment: You're not using strict and warnings, are you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
while ($res ==~ /of about <b>([1234567890,]<\/b> +)/) {
```

Has the following errors:

- While statement will cause an endless loop if the string matches,
  because...
- ...the regex lacks the `/g` global option, which would be useless
  because...
- ...I assume this match will happen only once.
- `[1234567890,]` will only match one character, and is better written
  `[0-9,]+`. Note the plus sign at the end to allow multiple matches.
- `==~` should be `=~`
- `$res` should probably be `$res->content`, like a'r stated in the
  comment.
- Your capture group extends beyond the `</b>` tag, which I suppose is
  a typo?

Also, you print out the whole `$res` object, when you probably only want to print the number.
More correct version:

```
if ($res->content =~ /of about <b>([0-9,]+)/) { print $1 }
```